# Unble to Select item from drop downs

Tags: drop-down-menu

I am unable to select an item from a drop down menu.

Please find the html code below,

```
<html> 
    <select id="UserNewRoleId" class="selectpicker " name="data[UserNew][role_id]" style="display: none;">
        <option value="">--Role--</option>
        <option value="36">System Admin</option>
        <option value="40">Billing</option>
        <option value="161">VenuRole</option>
        <option value="197">Reporting</option>
        <option value="212">DemoTesting</option>
        <option value="215">TestingRole</option>
        <option value="225">VenuRole1</option>
        <option value="241">P1</option>
        <option value="251">Admin</option>
        <option value="260">fghfghgfh</option>
        <option value="261">ghjhgj</option>
        <option value="271">TestNewVenu</option>
        <option value="280">Auditor</option>
    </select>
    <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" data-id="UserNewRoleId" title="--Role--">
        <div class="dropdown-menu open">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
        </div>
        <li class="selected" rel="0">
        <li rel="1">
        <li rel="2">
        <li rel="3">
        <li rel="4">
        <li rel="5">
        <li rel="6">
        <li rel="7">
        <li rel="8">
        <li rel="9">
        <li rel="10">
        <li rel="11">
        <li rel="12">
        <li rel="13">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Can you please let me know how to select items from drop down.
I tried the following ways .

```
xpath ="/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/d`enter code here`iv/div/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/button"
```

and

```
Id="UserNewRoleId"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just formatted your code. Now you can easily see, that you have the closing `</div>`-tag before you actually close your `<ul>`.

So I guess your inner `<div>` should look like this:

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu open">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
            <li class="selected" rel="0">
            <li rel="1">
            <li rel="2">
            <li rel="3">
            <li rel="4">
            <li rel="5">
            <li rel="6">
            <li rel="7">
            <li rel="8">
            <li rel="9">
            <li rel="10">
            <li rel="11">
            <li rel="12">
            <li rel="13">
        </ul>
    </div>
```